# Actualizar tabla con valores de otra tabla donde el registro es el más reciente

Tags: sql, update

tengo esto:

```
UPDATE A

SET A.Ultima_Gestion = G.fechaMx
FROM Asignado AS A

INNER JOIN (
    SELECT ID, MAX( [Fecha de gestion] ) AS fechaMx
    FROM Gestion 
    GROUP BY ID
) 
AS G

ON A.ID = G.ID;
```

Todo hasta ahí va bien. Actualizo mi tabla con el valor de la fecha más reciente agrupado por ID. Por ejemplo cuando "pasa" por el ID = 976 daría:

[image: Tabla]

y me actualiza esa fecha.

Lo que quiero es obtener de esa misma tabla el campo "Codigo_de_Resultado" y actualizarlo en mi tabla A (Asignado)

Para eso hice esto:

```
UPDATE A

SET A.Ultima_Gestion = G.coderesult
FROM Asignado AS A

INNER JOIN (
SELECT ID, MAX( [Fecha de gestion] ) , Codigo_Resultado AS coderesult
    FROM Gestion 
    GROUP BY ID, Codigo_Resultado, [Fecha de gestion] ORDER BY [Fecha de gestion] DESC
) AS G

ON A.ID = G.ID;
```

al "pasar" por 976 daría esto y pues obvio no funciona

```
SELECT ID, MAX( [Fecha de gestion] ) , Codigo_Resultado AS coderesult
    FROM Gestion WHERE ID = 976
    GROUP BY ID, Codigo_Resultado, [Fecha de gestion] ORDER BY [Fecha de gestion] DESC
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En resumen, para todos mis ID de la tabla Asignado (los ID no se repiten en esta)quiero traer el campo Codigo_de_Resultado de la tabla Gestiones (donde pueden repetirse muchos ID porque las gestiones son varias)con la fecha más reciente.

Les agradezco la ayuda!!

Comment: En la tabla Gestiones, tiene un campo Primary Key (claves principales) que no tiene valores duplicados?

Comment: Hola, si correcto. Un identity consecutivo que incrementa en uno

Comment: Es correcto si asumo la fila con el identity mas grande siempre tiene fecha de gestion mas reciente?

Comment: No siempre, porque el reporte me lo envian y el Id se lo creo yo. Sin embargo, antes de cargar los datos en mi tabla yo pdría ordenarlos por fecha para que queden como ud indica.

Comment: Porbaste con un select max?

Answer (score 0):

Usted puede probar este codigo para selectar las ID unicas con la fechas más recientes de la tabla Gestion.

```
SELECT G2.ID, G1.fechaMx, G2.Codigo_Resultado AS coderesult 
FROM
(
    (
        SELECT ID, MAX( [Fecha de gestion] ) AS fechaMx
        FROM Gestion 
        GROUP BY ID 
    ) AS G1

    JOIN

    Gestion AS G2   

    ON G1.ID = G2.ID 
    AND G1.fechaMx = G2.([Fecha de gestion])
) AS G3
```

Si tiene comprobar con un solo ID

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT G2.ID, G1.fechaMx, G2.Codigo_Resultado AS coderesult 
    FROM
    (
        (
            SELECT ID, MAX( [Fecha de gestion] ) AS fechaMx
            FROM Gestion 
            GROUP BY ID 
        ) AS G1

        JOIN

        Gestion AS G2   

        ON G1.ID = G2.ID 
        AND G1.fechaMx = G2.([Fecha de gestion])
    ) AS G3
)
WHERE ID = 976
```

Nota: No tengo el recurso apropriado para comprobar el syntax o la resulta de este codigo, asi hay posibilidades que tiene errores. Si encuentra errores, tiene que fijarlos antes de probar el query update.

Update:

```
UPDATE A
SET A.Ultima_Gestion = G3.coderesult
FROM 
(
    Asignado AS A

    JOIN

    SELECT G2.ID, G1.fechaMx, G2.Codigo_Resultado AS coderesult 
    FROM
    (
        (
            SELECT ID, MAX( [Fecha de gestion] ) AS fechaMx
            FROM Gestion 
            GROUP BY ID 
        ) AS G1

        JOIN

        Gestion AS G2   

        ON G1.ID = G2.ID 
        AND G1.fechaMx = G2.([Fecha de gestion])
    ) AS G3

    ON A.ID = G3.ID
)
```

Comment: Esto es una respuesta o un comentario? porque OP pregunta como hacer el update. y aca no veo ningun update